# How to replace a space exactly with "\\\\s+"

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am trying to use relaceAll to replace a space with "\\s+" but instead of replacing with desired characters it's considering it as space,
Here is my code:

```
String text = "hello  world !".replaceAll("\\s+", "\\\\s+");
```

My expected output is:

```
hello\\s+world\\s+!
```

Comment: If you want to replace **a space**, you could use```replace(" ","\\\\s+")```, but it doesn't look like that is actually what you want.

Comment: @khelwood 1) don't post answers as comments 2) `'\\\\s+` isn't a character...